# Multiple same output triggering

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script to match the two values. One is from my input and another one is i had taken from the query in domain domain server to get the certain values. i need match the my input values and queried output values. But if run the script the means it gives multiple same outputs. please find the attached output screenshots and my scripts.

```
$Inputui = Read-Host "Enter" –AsSecureString
$results = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} | FT samAccountName
foreach ($result in $results)
   {
       if($Inputui -match $result)
       {
   
      Write-output "ID Available"

      }
             
      else {

        Write-output "ID Not Available"

      }
      }
```

[image: Outputs]

Comment: If you are using `Read-Host` just to accept a `SamAcccountName`, then you do not need to use the `-AsSecureString` switch parameter. This will never match the string returned by the `SamAccountName` property. You are also formatting the output of the `Get-ADUser` function as a table i.e. `FT SamAccountName`, replace it with `Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems you want to test if a SamAccountname given through `Read-Host` can be found in the domain, correct?

Then:

- do not use `Format-*` cmdlets if you need to process the result further, because these cmdlets are for **display purposes only**
  your code now tries to compare a **string** against a [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.2#outputs) object
- remove `-AsSecureString`. You only need that to convert a given string (password) into a SecureString
- the `-Filter` parameter should actually be a **string**, not a scriptblock

```
$Inputui = Read-Host "Enter user SamAccountName"
Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq '$false'" | ForEach-Object {
    # using -match results in a partial match, just like 
    # $Inputui -like "*$($_.SamAccountName)*" would do
    # if you want an exact match, use the -eq operator instead
    if ($Inputui -match $_.SamAccountName) {
        Write-Host "ID Available"
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "ID Not Available"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the match is failed and entering into else block. Try below code

```
$Inputui = Read-Host "Enter" –AsSecureString
Get-AdUser -filter -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} | where-object {$_ -contains "$Inputui"} | FT samAccountName
```